# Umlaute not displayed correctly when loading .mdb MS Access into QGIS with eVis

Tags: qgis, ms-access, internationalization

I am loading an .mdb (MS Access 97 or 2003) to QGIS (1.9.0-Master) via the eVis database connection. Connecting to the mdb,  selecting a table and displaying it as a point-layer through the appropriate x/y-fields works fine.

However, in the attribute table the German Umlaute ä, ö, ü and also ß are displayed as inverted "?".

The umlaute in the mdb / attribute table are displayed correctly in ArcMap.

How do I get this running in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in this way :
Layer Properties (Eigenschaften)> General (Allgemein) > Data source coding (Datenquellenkodierung) 
There choose UTF-8